# Glassfish 4 can't enable remote admin?

Tags: java, glassfish, remote-access, glassfish-4

I have a Glassfish 4 server running on a headless Debian VM. I can access the application just fine, but I cannot seem to access the admin port from anything other than localhost. I'd like to be able to access it so I can remotely deploy/debug from an IDE on another machine.

I've tried the `asamin enable-secure-admin` command, which completes but after restarting there is no change.

I've checked with `netstat` and Glassfish is only listening on port `4848` from `localhost`. Is there any other place remote admin is controlled from? Or something I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe start by running `asadmin> list *` and seeing if you can figure out which property you need to set.  See if you can correlate that with a property you find by running `grep localhost ...` on the Glassfish config file(s) (which I no longer remember the location of, sorry.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the list command, that helped me figure out what property to set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the following to administer Glassfish remotely:

- set a non-blank password for all admin logins
- enable secure admin
- ensure the network listener is listening on the correct IP addresses (it could be set to listen only on the loopback interface)

Comment: Is there a command to change the network listener from localhost to an ip?

Comment: Changing the network listener using the "set" command did the trick.

Comment: @Austin, could you remember what exactly did you do? Seems like I have to do the same :)

Answer (score 1):

For me it works as follows:

*log into the glassfish admin console locally

*set admin-listener port to **1**4848 (I don`t know what is wrong with 4848, my JVM permanently uses it thus the admin console port changes **automatically**)

*set admin-listener IP to *my-host-IP* (different from the default 0.0.0.0 and from 127.0.0.1)

*add a new FireWall (I`ve ordered VPS on Windows) rule for outcoming TCP access to 14848 port

*run default glassfish domain

```
asadmin start-domain
```

*enable secure admin

```
asadmin --host my-host-IP --port 14848 enable-secure-admin
```

*restart the domain (and don`t forget to kill Java possibly loitering in memory)